# Calculate value of text from a dictionary of words in Java 8

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8

I'm having trouble transforming my algo in a Java 8 view.

I have an `arrayList` composed of Articles

```
ArrayList<Article> listArticles = new ArrayList<>();
```

With an Article composed like this

```
public class Article {
    private String titleArticle;
    private String abstractArticle;
    private String textArticle;
    private Long value;
}
```

and on the other side I have map of words with each one a value associated

```
HashMap<String, Long> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
```

I want to get the value of an article. The value of an article is calculated based on the words in the title, abstract and text (all added up together)

In Java 7 I would do something like this (I hope I didn't make any mistake here)

```
for(Article article : dataArticles){
    double valueArticle = 0;

    for(Map.Entry<String, Long> word : dataDictionary.entrySet()){

         //looping through the words in the title
         for(String text : article.getTitle().split(" ")){
            if(text.equalsIgnoreCase(word.getKey())){
                valueArticle += word.getValue();
            }
         }
         //looping through the words in the abstract
         for(String text : article.getAbstractText().split(" ")){
            if(text.equalsIgnoreCase(word.getKey())){
                valueArticle += word.getValue();
            }
         }
         //looping through the words in the abstract
         for(String text : article.getText().split(" ")){
            if(text.equalsIgnoreCase(word.getKey())){
                valueArticle += word.getValue();
            }
         }
    }

    article.setValue(valueArticle);
}
```

How can I calculate the value of each article inside the Array by reducing the time process? 
I was thinking of using lambdas but maybe it's a bad approach. 
I'm new to Java 8 and trying to learn it.

*After some developing*

Still looking around how to make my `ArrayList` using streams. In the meantime I wanted, as well, to sort out the list from greatest article value to lowest article value.
I imagined that it would be something like this

```
Comparator<Article> byArticleValue = (a1, a2) ->
Integer.compare(a1.getValue(), a2.getValue());
dataArticles.stream()
        .sorted(byArticleValue);
```

But my list comes out unsorted. What am I doing wrong in this case ?

Comment: It looks like the numbers are `long`, but you use `double` in your calculations. Why?

Comment: On first hand I was using doubles but it appeared to me that my numbers will only be entire numbers. It's a copy paste mistake. I've edited the code accordingly

Comment: for sorting, try to use: dataArticles.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Article::getValue));

Comment: I would suggest to open another question for the sorting issue - the existing answers are only related to the initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dictionary keys are not lower case, you should create a lower-cased version and re-use it:

```
/**
 * Create a copy of the dictionary with all keys in lower case.
 * @param lc a dictionary of lowercase words to their value
 * @param article the article to be evaluated
 */
static Map<String, Double> convert(Map<String, Double> dictionary) 
{
  return
      dictionary.entrySet().stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().toLowerCase(), 
               Map.Entry::getValue, 
               (p, q) -> p + q));
}
```

Then, for each article, you can quickly compute a value using a stream pipeline:

```
/**
 * Compute the value of an article.
 * @param lc a dictionary of lowercase words to their value
 * @param article the article to be evaluated
 */
static double evaluate(Map<String, Double> lc, Article article)
{
  return
      Stream.of(article.getTitle(), article.getAbstractText(), article.getText())
      .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.toLowerCase().split(" ")))
      .mapToDouble(k -> lc.getOrDefault(k, 0D))
      .sum();
}
```

For more flexibility in folding words together, you could use a [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) to index with a `CollationKey` rather than lowercase words. A similar enhancement could be made for [tokenizing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) the text, rather than simply splitting on spaces.

Answer (score 2):

The hash map can do very fast lookups.  If you reorganize your code a bit, you can get huge runtime savings.

```
long getValueOfText(String text) {
    long value = 0;
    for(String word : text.split(" ")) {
        Long v = dataDictionary.get(word);
        if (v != null) {
            value += v;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

That call to `get` is *almost free*.  No matter how many words you store in your map, it will take a constant time to look one up.

EDIT: it looks a bit nicer as a Java 8 stream

```
long getValueOfText(String text) {
    return Arrays.stream(text.split(" "))
                .map(word -> dataDictionary.get(word))
                .filter(v -> v != null)
                .reduce(Long::sum).get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast proposition Neal. I'll look that up and get back asap

Comment: It gets it done a bit more faster, but I was wondering if using streams is a possibility

Answer (score 0):

The Java 8 way of doing this is by utilizing Streams.

You can read about them here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html & Part 2: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2-2227132.html

Here is some sample code:

```
public static Map<string, integer=""> wordCount(Stream<String> stream) {
    return stream
      .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.split("\\s+")))
      .collect(Collectors
        .toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum)); 
}
```

Instead of looping through elements, you can process the data with a stream and use its methods to sort and organize through it. In the sample code above, the `flatmap` method separates lines of text into words and the `collect` method gathers them into a `Map<String, Integer>`, with the key being the word and the value being its count.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, then we have to map each word to an individual number - and sum these numbers up. Your code seems to just "count" the words (maps each word to the number "1").

Answer (score -1):

**Java8 Streaming API** is the way to go. It will make your code much faster and allows optional multi-threading.

I rewrote your code into this compilable example:

```
public class Snippet {

    static ArrayList<Article> listArticles = new ArrayList<>();
    static HashMap<String, Long> dictionary = new HashMap<>();

    private static void calculateWordValueSums(ArrayList<Article> listArticles) {

        // turn your list of articles into a stream
        listArticles.stream()

        // allow multi-threading (remove this line if you expect to have few articles)
        .parallel()

        // make calculation per article
        .forEach(article -> {

            // set the "value" field in the article as the result
            article.value =

                    // combine title, abstract and text, since they are counting all together
                    Stream.of(article.titleArticle, article.abstractArticle, article.textArticle)

                    // split every text into words (consider "\s" for to allow tabs as separators)
                    .flatMap(text -> Arrays.stream(text.split(" ")))

                    // allow multi-threading (remove this line if you expect to have few words per article)
                    .parallel()

                    // convert words into their corresponding integer value
                    .mapToLong(dictionary::get)

                    // sum all Longs
                    .sum();

            System.out.println(article.value);
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Article a = new Article();
        a.titleArticle = "a b c";
        a.abstractArticle = "d e";
        a.textArticle = "f g h";
        listArticles.add(a);

        dictionary.put("a", 1l);
        dictionary.put("b", 1l);
        dictionary.put("c", 1l);
        dictionary.put("d", 1l);
        dictionary.put("e", 1l);
        dictionary.put("f", 1l);
        dictionary.put("g", 1l);
        dictionary.put("h", 1l);

        calculateWordValueSums(listArticles);
    }
}

class Article {
    String titleArticle;
    String abstractArticle;
    String textArticle;
    long value;
}
```

You should, however, rethink your `Article` class. The field `value` will be null, until the calculation is done. Consider having an `Article` class with just the inputs for the calculation and an `ArticleWithResultValue` class, which contains a reference to the article and the resulting value. This will give you compiler help, about whether or not the calculation is already done.

Comment: Ooops, my answer has been downvoted. Please let me know how to improve my answer.

Comment: Looks pretty good to me. You should handle differences in case and words that aren't in the dictionary though.